# Use recursion to get all children of node in Bigquery SQL table

Tags: sql, recursion, graph, google-bigquery

I'm working with a dataset in bigquery that has parent-child relationships, but doesn't indicate final_parent...

My data looks something like this:

```
| id   | parent  |
| -----| --------|
| AA   | AB      |
| AB   | AC      |
| ..   | ..      |
```

The rows are either questions or answers, all answers roll up to a single question, but the you can answer an answer so there is this recursive graph structure... What I want is to get all the answers to a single question, starting with the row id of that question...

I generated the following query - I think it is logically correct for the task:

```
WITH RECURSIVE tbl_1 AS(
    (SELECT *
    FROM source_table 
    WHERE (id = xxxxxxxxxxx) OR (parent = xxxxxxxxxxx)) 
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT *
      FROM source_table 
      WHERE (parent IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM tbl_1) 
        AND (id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM tbl_1)))) 
   )

SELECT *
FROM tbl_1
```

However I get the following error...

```
ERROR:
 400 A recursive reference from inside an expression subquery is not allowed at [9:49]
```

I think this is just something that hasn't been implemented yet in bigquery? Any advice on how to do it despite this? Thanks so much!!

Comment: Would you try it again after removing parentheses wrapping **SELECT** statements in **tbl_1** CTE first ?

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
with recursive tbl as (
  select *, 1 pos  from your_table 
  where question not in (select answer from your_table) 
  union all
  select t1.question, t2.answer, pos + 1
  from tbl t1 
  join your_table t2
  on t2.question = t1.answer
)
select question, string_agg(answer order by pos) answers
from tbl
group by question
```

for dummy data as in below example

[image]

the output is

[image]